# React parent function calls child's nested componentDidMount function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I'm using D3 with react and I need to run the resize function whenever handleClick() is run by the parent or perhaps simply if the toggle state is changed. What is the best way to approach this?
**Parent Component**

```
class Wrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            toggle: true
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        if (!this.state.toggle) {
            this.setState({toggle: true})
        } else { 
            this.setState({toggle: false})
        }
    }
    render() {
       const toggled = this.state.toggle ? 'toggled' : '';
       return (
           <div id="wrapper" className={toggled}>
               <UnitedStatesMap />
           </div>
       );
    }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
class UnitedStatesMap extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            activeState: d3.select(null)
        };
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        function resize() {
            if(activeState[0][0]) { reset() };
            width = document.getElementById('page-content-wrapper').offsetWidth;
            height = width * mapRatio;

            projection
                .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
                .scale(width);

            svg
                .style('width', `${width}px`)
                .style('height', `${height}px`)

            svg.select('rect')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height)

            g.selectAll('.state').attr('d', path);
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <div id="map" ref="map"></div>
            )
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Wrapper` pass `toggle` to `UnitedStatesMap`

```
<UnitedStatesMap toggle={this.state.toggle} />
```

In `UnitedStatesMap` add

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.toggle !== nextProps.toggle) {
    // call resize
  }
}
```

Obviously, you'll have to move your `resize` function into its own instance method and then just call it in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: I have a lot of d3 related variables inside of componentDidMount that reset() relies on. What is the 'React Way' of giving reset() access to those variables if I'm pulling it out of the scope of componentDidMount()?

Comment: @Groovietunes Depends on what all is happening in that function that you're not showing here. If you have no state you could just put everything that's currently in `componentDidMount` into its own instance method `myReset = () => { ... }` and then just do `this.myReset()` in both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` (as shown above)